# Revisar si especifica clase esta siendo usada en alguna solución

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Estoy en un proyecto muy extenso donde tengo aproximadamente 30 soluciones y se me dio el requerimiento de verificar si cierta clase esta siendo utilizada en alguna de estas soluciones.

Ejemplo: la clasee NombreClase1.cs esta siendo utilizada en la solución Nombresolucionejemplo.

El tema es que no siempre la clase esta bajo un nombre de  carpeta igual ala de la solución y quería consultar si existe algún método eficiente para saber si una clase X esta siendo utilizada en alguna de las apps.(soluciones).

Ejemplo :la clase Nombreclase2.cs esta siendo utilizada en la solucion 1 2 y 3 o ninguna .

Comment: Puedes usar alguna aplicación tipo AstroGrep para buscar en el código donde se referencia, o hacer una pequeña app tu mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te sugiero que hagas para este caso es aprovechar herramientas como el buscador de palabras que trae *Visual Studio* o algún programa externo que se encargue de buscar alguna coincidencia del nombre de la clase entre los archivos de las soluciones.

> **Usar el buscador de palabras:**
>
> Tienes que aprovechar que esta herramienta la trae incluida Visual
> Studio y demás IDEs o editores de texto.
>
> En el caso de Visual Studio, esta herramienta se invoca con el atajo
> de teclado `Ctrl + F` y lo puedes configurar para que busque el
> término que quieras  en diferentes espacios de tu solución. Para tu
> caso, lo pones para que busque en toda la solución y así encontrar si
> la clase que mencionas se utiliza en esa solución.
>
> El único inconveniente es que tienes que abrir solución por solución y
> buscar.
>
> **Usar un programa externo:**
>
> Podrías usar un programa externo como **[AstroGrep](https://sourceforge.net/projects/astrogrep/)** para buscar
> así coincidencias de una palabra en un conjunto de archivos.
>
> En tu caso, puedes usar **[AstroGrep](https://sourceforge.net/projects/astrogrep/)** para buscar el nombre de tu
> clase en los archivos de tus soluciones para saber si se está usando
> la clase en estas soluciones.
>
> **Búsqueda en las referencias de cada solución:**
>
> Aunque no es recomendable, puedes también, en el caso de que para usar
> la clase incluyan en las soluciones la librería que contiene la clase
> tomada del compilado de la solución original de la clase, puedes
> verificar si esa librería se encuentra en las referencias de los
> proyectos.
>
> El inconveniente de hacer eso es que la existencia de la librería en
> una solución no te garantiza que se usa o no la clase que buscas y que
> tendrías que buscarlo solución por solución.